# How to Deploy Laravel 5 on shared cPanel hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, cpanel

I've been successful in deploying Laravel 4 applications on shared hosts by simply editing the paths here at /bootstrap/paths.php.

However, Laravel 5 does not have that file. How does Laravel 5 manage paths? I have access to the root directory with public_html. I can upload all the files to root and public directories, but confused where to look for the paths to be maintained?

Comment: [Here](http://www.fortrabbit.com/) [are](https://www.linode.com/) [some](https://www.soyoustart.com/en/) [solutions](https://www.leaseweb.com/bare-metal-server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5 is smart enough to detect all it's path. I was missing some of the files during upload. :)

What I did was upload all the files as it is structured and the content of public folder was uploaded into the www directory, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You can play with creating new Application() in bootstrap/app.php. Its constructor takes argument which tells where is rest of the application related to public/index.php

Currently app.php has

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

Change the /../ to something else if rest of the application folders for example in ../laravel/ compared to index.html

Comment: can you please elaborate? I didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cPanel in your shared hosting you can try these easier methods before trying to move the Laravel's `public` folder:

1. Often you also have an SSH access when you have cPanel on shared hostings, so you can replace the `www` folder (i.e. the *website document root*) with a **symbolic link** to `[app]/public`, then deploy your Laravel app inside the `[app]` folder.
2. If you are deploying on a **subdomain**, e.g. `[app].example.com`, usually with cPanel you can choose the document root, then you can simply set it to `[app]/public`.

I think the two methods above are both easier and safer than moving the `public` folder. I would keep this as the last option.

Take a look here for some more info: http://blog.netgloo.com/2016/01/29/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting/